# No cobertura code coverage in SonarQube, Azure DevOps displays it right

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, cobertura

We have a product written in Java that is built using Azure DevOps. The issue being faced is SonarQube showing 0.0% code coverage. Azure DevOps publish code coverage task is able to pick up the results and show it in code coverage tab without any issues.

Here are the tasks being used -

[image]

1. I have a simple SonarQube publish task immediately after the above two tasks. The commented *codeCoverageToolOption: Cobertura* did not make any difference when uncommented.
2. The Cobertura plugin is installed in our SonarQube instance
3. The Karma tests are run before SonarQube analysis.

**Some logs** -

Prepare Analysis Configuration step -

```
##[debug]loading INPUT_SONAR.VERBOSE
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90_USERNAME
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading SECRET_BLACKDUCK_VERSIONNAME
##[debug]loading SECRET_VSTSTOKEN
##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loaded 18
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
##[debug]SonarQube=5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90
##[debug]5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90=<redacted>
##[debug]5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90 auth param apitoken = null
##[debug]5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90 auth param username = ***
##[debug]5daf3e07-cbfb-436b-bc15-1d35da29eb90 auth param password = null
##[debug]organization=null
##[debug]scannerMode=Other
##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/server/version' with query "undefined"
##[debug]Response: 200 Body: "6.7.5.38563"
##[debug]extraProperties=sonar.projectKey=<redacted>
sonar.projectName=<redacted>
sonar.projectVersion=<redacted>
sonar.branch.name=sonarqube_fix
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=coverage/cobertura/cobertura-coverage.xml
##[debug]set SONARQUBE_SCANNER_MODE=Other
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=SONARQUBE_SCANNER_MODE;issecret=false;]Other
##[debug]set SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT=********
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT;issecret=true;]***
##[debug]set SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS={"sonar.host.url":"<redacted>","sonar.login":***,"sonar.projectKey":"<redacted","sonar.projectName":"<redacted>","sonar.projectVersion":"redacted","sonar.branch.name":"sonarqube_fix","sonar.sourceEncoding":"UTF-8","sonar.dynamicAnalysis":"reuseReports","sonar.java.coveragePlugin":"cobertura","sonar.cobertura.reportPath":"coverage/cobertura/cobertura-coverage.xml"}
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS;issecret=false;]{"sonar.host.url":"<redacted>","sonar.login":***,"sonar.projectKey":"<redacted>","sonar.projectName":"<redacted>","sonar.projectVersion":"<redacted>","sonar.branch.name":"sonarqube_fix","sonar.sourceEncoding":"UTF-8","sonar.dynamicAnalysis":"reuseReports","sonar.java.coveragePlugin":"cobertura","sonar.cobertura.reportPath":"coverage/cobertura/cobertura-coverage.xml"}
##[section]Finishing: Prepare analysis on SonarQube
```

There is no separate "Run Analysis" task as this is a Gradle task. Here's the output (redacted irrelevant parts)

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'gradlew build'
##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Result: True
##[section]Starting: gradlew build
==============================================================================
Task         : Gradle
Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
Version      : 2.151.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613720
==============================================================================
##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=/vsts/agent/_work/_temp
##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
##[debug]loading INPUT_WRAPPERSCRIPT
##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
##[debug]loading INPUT_TASKS
##[debug]loading INPUT_PUBLISHJUNITRESULTS
##[debug]loading INPUT_TESTRESULTSFILES
##[debug]loading INPUT_CODECOVERAGETOOL
##[debug]loading INPUT_CLASSFILESDIRECTORIES
##[debug]loading INPUT_FAILIFCOVERAGEEMPTY
##[debug]loading INPUT_JAVAHOMESELECTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_JDKVERSION
##[debug]loading INPUT_JDKARCHITECTURE
##[debug]loading INPUT_GRADLEOPTS
##[debug]loading INPUT_SQANALYSISENABLED
##[debug]loading INPUT_SQGRADLEPLUGINVERSIONCHOICE
##[debug]loading INPUT_SQGRADLEPLUGINVERSION
##[debug]loading INPUT_CHECKSTYLEANALYSISENABLED
##[debug]loading INPUT_FINDBUGSANALYSISENABLED
##[debug]loading INPUT_PMDANALYSISENABLED
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading SECRET_SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT
##[debug]loading SECRET_BLACKDUCK_VERSIONNAME
##[debug]loading SECRET_VSTSTOKEN
##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loaded 25
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
##[debug]check path : /vsts/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.151.0/task.json
##[debug]adding resource file: /vsts/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.151.0/task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]wrapperScript=/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew
##[debug]check path : /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew
##[debug]cwd=/vsts/agent/_work/1/s
##[debug]check path : /vsts/agent/_work/1/s
##[debug]javaHomeSelection=JDKVersion
##[debug]codeCoverageTool=None
##[debug]failIfCoverageEmpty=false
##[debug]publishJUnitResults=true
##[debug]testResultsFiles=/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/**/TEST-*.xml
##[debug]tasks=build
##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=/vsts/agent/_work/1/s
##[debug]which '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew'
##[debug]found: '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew'
##[debug]which '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew'
##[debug]found: '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew'
##[debug]options=null
##[debug]/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew arg: ["build"]
##[debug]Using JDK version to find and set JAVA_HOME
##[debug]jdkVersion=default
##[debug]jdkArchitecture=x64
##[debug]Agent.Version=2.152.1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TaskHub;feature=Gradle]{"jdkVersion":"default"}
##[debug]gradleOpts=-Xmx1024m
##[debug]GRADLE_OPTS is now set to -Xmx1024m
##[debug]Enabled code coverage successfully
##[debug]sqAnalysisEnabled=true
SonarQube analysis is enabled.
##[debug]sqGradlePluginVersionChoice=specify
##[debug]sqGradlePluginVersion=2.7.1
##[debug]/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew arg: ["-I","/vsts/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.151.0/node_modules/codeanalysis-common/sonar.gradle"]
##[debug]/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew arg: ["sonarqube"]
##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=/vsts/agent/_work/1/s
##[debug]build.artifactStagingDirectory=/vsts/agent/_work/1/a
##[debug]build.buildNumber=20190607.4
##[debug]checkstyleAnalysisEnabled=false
##[debug]findbugsAnalysisEnabled=false
##[debug]pmdAnalysisEnabled=false
##[debug]Getting credentials for account feeds
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[debug]Got auth token
##[debug]exec tool: /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   build
##[debug]   -I
##[debug]   /vsts/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.151.0/node_modules/codeanalysis-common/sonar.gradle
##[debug]   sonarqube
[command]/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew build -I /vsts/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.151.0/node_modules/codeanalysis-common/sonar.gradle sonarqube
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.8.1-bin/e8p42vx1m7a3mz9ydmjagn6wn/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.8.1-bin/e8p42vx1m7a3mz9ydmjagn6wn
Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.8.1-bin/e8p42vx1m7a3mz9ydmjagn6wn/gradle-4.8.1/bin/gradle

Welcome to Gradle 4.8.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Dependency locking
 - Maven Publish and Ivy Publish plugins improved and marked stable
 - Incremental annotation processing enhancements
 - APIs to configure tasks at creation time

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :war
> Task :copyArtifacts
> Task :distZip
> Task :assemble

> Task :compileTestJava

> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
Note: /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/src/<redacted>ModuleQueriesTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :junitPlatformTest
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
2019-06-07 08:35:01,972 main ERROR Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:250)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:194)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterAllMatching(Server.java:335)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:259)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:164)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:556)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
    at <redacted>.<clinit>(filename.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor102.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:14)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:144)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:59)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:122)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMock(MockCreator.java:70)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:47)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:204)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:118)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:63)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:93)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.executeTests(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.invoke(CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.java:33)
    at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.execute(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.executeTests(ConsoleLauncher.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.main(ConsoleLauncher.java:41)

╷‌
Test run finished after 11605 ms
[         9 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         9 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         9 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[       109 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[       109 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[       109 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]


> Task :test SKIPPED
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build

> Task :sonarqube
Property 'sonar.abap.file.suffixes' is not declared as multi-values/property set but was read using 'getStringArray' method. The SonarQube plugin declaring this property should be updated.
Unable to create a corresponding matcher for custom assertion method, please check the format of the following symbol: ''

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 55s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed

<redacted irrelevant lines> 
##[debug]  /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/coverage/cobertura (directory)
##[debug]  /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/coverage/cobertura/cobertura-coverage.xml (file)
##[debug]  /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/node_modules/istanbul/lib/report/cobertura.js (file)

##[debug]14121 results
##[debug]found 14121 paths
##[debug]applying include pattern
##[debug]2 matches
##[debug]2 final results
##[debug]testRunTitle=null
##[debug]Reading test results from file '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/build/test-results/junit-platform/TEST-junit-jupiter.xml'
No Result Found to Publish '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/build/test-results/junit-platform/TEST-junit-jupiter.xml'.
##[debug]Reading test results from file '/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/build/test-results/junit-platform/TEST-junit-vintage.xml'
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[results.publish type=JUnit;mergeResults=true;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/build/test-results/junit-platform/TEST-junit-jupiter.xml,/vsts/agent/_work/1/s/build/test-results/junit-platform/TEST-junit-vintage.xml;testRunSystem=VSTS - gradle;]
##[debug]task result: Succeeded
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Build succeeded.
##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
Publishing test results to test run '1028438'
Test results remaining: 109. Test run id: 1028438
Published Test Run : <URL redacted> 
##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
##[section]Finishing: gradlew build
```

How to resolve this?